# how to get element from a table, to be selected in playwright python

Tags: python, playwright

[image]

for example, it passes the 'ids' but I would just like to download from the table that contains the description 'Edição 993 link direto gdb' and the next ones that come.
I tried to bring it with page.inner_html("tbody"), but I'm new to python, programming in general, do you have any suggestions of what I can do to get it?

Comment: using the query selector, it returns 'JHHandle@node', need to find a way to return it, or value of Ids, or a way to get this upload link when it's the latest in 'Edição'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the id you will need the parent, and evaluate the id attribute

```js
const td = page.locator("text=Edição 993 link direto gdb");
const tr = await td.$('xpath=..')
const id = await tr.evaluate(node => node.getAttribute('id'))
```

Comment: sorry in python what would be the equivalent of this $?

Comment: because in this table there are other ids, Edition '*' direct link gdb: example 'Edição 992, 991' I'm trying to get only the biggest of these

Comment: I ACHIEVED!!! thanks a lot for the help, page.locator('text=link direto gdb >> nth=0')